# now() function redeclared

Tags: codeigniter, magento

I am using a hybrid system that is an ExpressionEngine CMS, which is build with CodeIgniter, and Magento as a store "off to the side" and working together.

We cannot upgrade the existing installation because the contractor that initially built the system did some very weird stuff to the core code that keeps us from upgrading so I am looking to start fresh.

I installed Magento Community 1.8.1 alongside EE 2.7.2.

I wrote a plugin for EE that gets the cart info and the logged in user info but when using the plugin, I get the error:

```
Cannot redeclare now() (previously declared in \codeigniter\system\helpers\date_helper.php:40) in \store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php on line 123
```

How do I circumvent this without modifying core code on either system?

I also receive errors in other files because it is declared in them as well, such as \store\app\code\core\Mage\Admin\Resource\User.php; I get this one when attempting to login to the BO.

Comment: I have this exact same issue, did you ever find out what the issue was?

Comment: You mean you are also using Magento and EE together?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I have Magento as the main site for shopping and use EE for the CMS and pull EE content into Magento.  Work great until I upgrade EE from 2.2 to 2.7.3

Comment: Our site is the other way around. We use the EE CMS as our main site and only use the shopping cart portion of Magento. It is really kind of a stupid setup, if you ask me, but I was not the one that built it. I only have to maintain it.

Comment: I believe it has to do with Magento's autoloader. It changed between releases as our Magento 1.0.4.1 -> EE 2.5.2 site doesn't have the problem. There are a lot of times where I call Magento code in our EE templates. I've actually had to move the code out into an external script and call the script from my EE plugin using cURL. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I circumvent this without modifying core code on either system?

My guess: you can't.

A `now()` function is being declared in [CodeIgniter's Date helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/date_helper.html) (which is a core file), and in Magento's functions.php (which is also a core file, by the looks of the file path).

EE uses CI's Date helper in various places, so you can't avoid it...

Comment: Any idea when this was put into Magento as we have the two products working together with no issues now, although they are older versions.

Comment: Nope. No idea. Never worked with Magento.

Comment: I am looking at our older versions and the code for the function now() is exactly the same in both versions as it is in the newer versions. I need to look at where the date_helper is being called because I think that may be the issue.

Comment: I'm gonna accept this as it has gone away but I cannot login to Magento BO and that is beyond scope of this forum.

Comment: Note that the functions in CI's Date helper are wrapped in a `function_exists()` conditional, so *if* you can load Magento before EE, you *might* be able to avoid it. However, that could mean you break EE, because it will then use Magento's `now()`, instead of CI's one.

Comment: Yes, I know that and they are totally different code.